# Passport Renewal

Tags: pakistani-citizens, passport-renewals

I'm a Pakistani citizen traveling to Pakistan from Melbourne on 1st Feb 2017. My passport expires in April 2017.

Will I be allowed to exit Australia with this passport?

I'll renew my passport from Pakistan before coming back but I was not sure about going from here with a layover in Bangkok for 13 hours inside the airport during my travel to Pakistan.

Answer (score 1):

When going to the country that issued the passport it does not matter how little time is left (and sometimes not even whether it has already expired). Concern about remaining validity (often three or six months) is to make it easier to ship you out of the country you are visiting (eg Australia) but in this case Pakistan is your 'home' country, so that does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with your travel plans. Your passport expires well after your planned arrival in Pakistan so you do not have to worry about transit or travel issues.

I recommend using the new [online service](https://onlinemrp.dgip.gov.pk/) which makes the renewal process automated and very simple to use; you can only use this if you are out of Pakistan though. The only reason I mention this is because it is quicker (1-2 weeks) vs. the normal month or more it takes in person.

If your old passport contains a valid visa, make sure you carry both passports with you upon  your return to Australia.

Comment: If you have an Australian visa, you'll need to transfer it (electronically) to your new passport: http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/What-if-I-have-a-new-passport